# rails single authentication mixed with edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have a question on rails. I'm implementing a resource. The new/create actions are finished. Now I am working on the edit/update actions.

I want the user to have to input the password for the resource and then he can edit the values.

Either on two sites, so first "input password" and afterwards he can update the values, or just on one site where he has to enter the correct password and can update the values.

But I have no idea how to achieve this the best way.

Do you have any tips? I'm still a beginner.

Comment: So does every resource have a password, or do you mean the user's password?

Comment: every resource has a password. there are no users. only the resource has one. The resource is just a text which has a password. and only the person who has the password should be able to edit it

Answer (score 0):

Just have a :password field in params.  Then in your controller you can do this.

```
def update
  raise Unauthorized unless user.authenticate(params[:password])
  #normal update stuff
end
```

You will have load the user and define what Unauthorized error is in this situations.  You could also just render out and return a flash if you would rather go that route.

In the form you will just add an input field that

```
<%= f.text_field :password %>
```

Comment: hi! thanks for your answer. no I'm not using devise, I followed the tutorial of michael hartl. he is implementing his own authentication system and using the bcrypt gem for the password.

Comment: I would probably have to have all the form update fields for my resource and the password field on one page. then when the user edited the resource and typed in the password and submits, my controller must check whether the password is correct, and if it is correct the resource gets updated. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, just add the password field and then check it is correct before updating the resource.